# Open two files for comparison in FileMerge, from command line

Tags: command-line, xcode, macos

I have two files (in a project’s source code base) which I often want to compare visually in FileMerge, as part of a regular routine. I’m trying to script that routine for efficiency, but am stuck on automating this step.  **Is there a single shell command which will open two files for comparison in FileMerge?**

I tried `open file1.txt -a FileMerge` as a starting point, but this fails with an error message:

> […] FileMerge cannot open files in the “text” format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call FileMerge from the commandline, use `opendiff`:

```
opendiff file1.txt file2.txt
```

This will open Filemerge with the two files open and diff'd.